# I have a 24 Gb disk and a 1Tb Hard Disk How do I get Ubuntu to install on my 24 GB and my home dir on the 1TB

Tags: ubuntu, partition, home

I used the auto installer for Ubuntu on my 24GB drive my disk space looks like this.

```
kipke@ThePad:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       16395648 3936132  11603608  26% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             2981788       4   2981784   1% /dev
tmpfs             598380    1100    597280   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2991888     236   2991652   1% /run/shm
none              102400      32    102368   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1         497696    3376    494320   1% /boot/efi
```

[image: 24gb drive picture]

[image: 1tb drive picture]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just paste the text?

Comment: because I could not figure out how to put spaces between the columns of the terminal it was just a mess of text even when I used br tags.

Comment: Highlight the text and press the "code sample" button or put it in <pre> tags.

Comment: thanks but the other two are actually images of my disks application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the disk/partition already prepared (disk is partitioned FS created)
You need to add a new /home mount point to /etc/fstab It should be something like that:

```
(Your new disk partition)  (FS type)
/dev/sdX[1-9]   /home    ext4          defaults       0  2
```

then mount the partition to /mnt with:

```
mount /dev/sdX[1-9] /mnt
```

copy your /home to /mnt.

```
rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /mnt/.
```

afterwards, move your /home to a different directory for example /old_home

```
mv /home /old_home
```

Then you need to unmount the new partition

```
umount /mnt
```

Reboot your system or remount with

```
mount -a
```

Also please check the ubuntu help wiki, it's much easier to understand as my primitive  howto:) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: how exactly would I do that? I'm new to Linux, I literally have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you created the partitions on your 1TB disk ?