# How to make sda1 bigger / use default download files in sdb1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, disk, data

I run below command in ubuntu:

```
df -h
```

Output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            111G     0  111G   0% /dev
tmpfs            23G  8.7M   23G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        29G   22G  6.8G  77% /
tmpfs           111G     0  111G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           111G     0  111G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             64K     0   64K   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
/dev/sdb1       3.0T   72M  2.9T   1% /mnt
tmpfs            23G     0   23G   0% /run/user/1000
```

As stated `/dev/sda1` is getting full because of high amount of data download. And `/dev/sdb1` is unused. How can I make it `sda1` bigger or default download packages in `sdb1`?

```
sudo blkid

/dev/sr0: UUID="0E25076072645f72" LABEL="rd_rdfe_stable.160802-0931" TYPE="udf"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="b2e47a31-37fe-4914-b333-bd1c2a2dacae" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c74ad4d8-01"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="5ca1e85e-5631-473a-869f-27b6dafb2d20" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="75cef133-3c23-4d58-a1b6-dab98f8b633c"
```

Upon running this command:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

> CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
>   UUID=b2e47a31-37fe-4914-b333-bd1c2a2dacae       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
>
> CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
>
> The following is used to dynamically configured additional
>
> NICs. Do not remove unless you know what you are doing.
>
> none /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d tmpfs   nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=64K 0 0
>   /dev/sdb1       /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,comment=cloudconfig     0       2

Which one is easier option. And how can I do it?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/i-have-a-24-gb-disk-and-a-1tb-hard-disk-how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-install-on-my-24

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you cannot make "/" (=root partition) bigger. Seem you have a 32GB SDD for fast access and a 3TB HDD for your data. It is up to you to save the data that need speed (e.g. OS) on the SSD and your data that is just big (e.g. data files, mp3, movies, etc.) on your HDD.

Normal setup would be to mount your HDD as /home and leave the rest on the SSD. This assumes that you only install a few programs and have all your data under /home/username/Documents, /home/username/Downloads, /home/username/Music, /home/username/Pictures, /home/username/Video, etc...

Note that in the end it will depend on your setup, e.g. if you use KVM/libvirt as a virtualization solution, your virtual machines (consuming GB of data) may land in /var/lib/libvirt, hence outside of your home directory.

Comment: mounting  /home on HDD with not really make things faster as 90% of what we access in linnux is in the /home directory. (For example if you install steam your games insall to /home/user/.local/steam....) So keep that in mind. Other then that then answer is correct.